# How to unbind from click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have modal window, this modal window has events:

```
$(document).on('click', '#TaskOutcomesTab .has-attachments-image', function(){
```

After close popup, I want to clear this handler. I've found success in solution, but I want to make it more general

```
        $(document).off("click", "#task-details .has-attachments-image");
        $(document).off("click", "#task-details .no-attachments-image");
        $(document).off("click", "#TaskOutcomesTab .has-attachments-image");
        $(document).off("click", "#TaskOutcomesTab .no-attachments-image");
```

I wanna something like that:

```
$(document).off("click")
```

or

```
$(document).off("click", ".has-attachments-image")
```

Comment: You can try `$(document).on('click', '[class$="-attachments-image" ]')`

Comment: `off('click')` works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/2o4eguwz/2/. You'd probably want to namespace it though, to prevent wiping out all delegated click handlers

Comment: No, this does not work.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan actually I didn't setup any namespace...but maybe it is issue...

Comment: If it's not working for you then we need to see a working example of that. In isolation it works fine, as the fiddle shows.